# Autofac: Register multiple

Tags: c#, autofac

A module has registered a type that looks like this:

```
class MyType
{
    public IEnumerable<IServer> Servers { get { ... } }
}
```

I would like to register each of these server instances with the container:

```
builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<MyType>().Servers).As<IEnumerable<IServer>>();
```

Separately I would like to register another implementation of IServer

```
builder.RegisterType<AnotherServer>().As<IServer>().SingleInstance;
```

Then I would like to get all the servers - the union os Server property and an instance of AnotherServer:

```
public MyClass(IEnumerable<IServer> allServers)
{
}
```

However, the above setup doesn't work because registering an actual instance of IEnumerable seems to override the Autofac behaviour of providing all registered implementations when an IEnumerable is requested.

Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have one registration to produce multiple component.

I can see two ways for resolving your issue

1. Create a new `IRegistrationSource` to resolve `IEnumerable<T>`. You can have a look at the [CollectionRegistrationSource.cs](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs) to see how to do it
2. Use a module to replace the `IEnumerable` during the activation.

Something like this :

```
public interface IContainer<T> { 
   IEnumerable<T> Values { get; }  
}

public class MyType : IContainer<IServer>
{
    public IEnumerable<IServer> Servers
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new Server1();
            yield return new Server2();
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<IServer> IContainer<IServer>.Values
    {
        get { return this.Servers; }
    }
}

public class AggregatedEnumerableModule<T> : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        if (registration.Activator.LimitType.IsArray)
        {
            Type elementType = registration.Activator.LimitType.GetElementType();
            if (elementType == typeof(T))
            {
                registration.Activating += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    IEnumerable<T> originalValues = (IEnumerable<T>)e.Instance;
                    IEnumerable<T> newValues = e.Context.Resolve<IContainer<T>>().Values;
                    IEnumerable<T> aggregatedValues = newValues.Concat(originalValues);

                    e.ReplaceInstance(aggregatedValues);
                };
            }
        }
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```

Then

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new AggregatedEnumerableModule<IServer>());
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IContainer<IServer>>();
builder.RegisterType<Server3>().As<IServer>();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

IEnumerable<IServer> pouets = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IServer>>();
```